# php mysqli_insert_id() error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get the last inserted query's id.. after some searching i found the

```
<?php mysqli_insert_id($getCarInfo); ?>
```

command, but i could not get it to work.

I am new to php and am using DreamWeaver CS6, this is the connection code that the dreamweaver created:

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_getCarInfo = "localhost";
$database_getCarInfo = "cars";
$username_getCarInfo = "root";
$password_getCarInfo = "*******";
$getCarInfo = mysql_pconnect($hostname_getCarInfo, $username_getCarInfo, $password_getCarInfo) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

i heard that there are different APIs and i seen that the connection is mysql_pconnect() and i am using mysqli_..();, i do not know how to handle those nor if that is the problem.

This is the generated error:

```
Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in H:\AppServ\www\cars\insertData.php on line 170
New Record has id 0.
```

This is line 170:

```
<?php printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($getCarInfo)); ?>
```

the data gets inserted successfully with no errors.. but i cannot get the ID back and that is very important for the registration to continue.

also, should i start a session? i need the ID to be paresed to another page so  i can ask for the images to upload them and associate them to the ID.. or how is it done exactly?

EDIT---

```
Full code:

getCarInfo.php:

    <?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_getCarInfo = "localhost";
$database_getCarInfo = "cars";
$username_getCarInfo = "root";
$password_getCarInfo = "****";
$getCarInfo = mysql_pconnect($hostname_getCarInfo, $username_getCarInfo, $password_getCarInfo) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

insertData.php:

```
    <?php require_once('Connections/getCarInfo.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO manufacturer (manufacturer) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['Manufacturer'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_getCarInfo, $getCarInfo);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $getCarInfo) or die(mysql_error());
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO car_specifications (id, manafacturer, model, `year`, type, cylinder, cylinder_cap, trans_count, trans_type, drive_type, fuel, hpower, valves, int_color, ext_color, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['manafacturer'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['model'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['year'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cylinder'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cylinder_cap'], "double"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['trans_count'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['trans_type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['drive_type'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['fuel'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hpower'], "int"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['valves'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['int_color'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['ext_color'], "text"),

                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image1'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image2'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image3'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image4'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image5'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image6'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image7'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image8'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image9'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['image10'], "text"));




  mysql_select_db($database_getCarInfo, $getCarInfo);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $getCarInfo) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">
  <input name="Manufacturer" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" />
  <input name="sbmit" type="submit" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />

</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
  <table align="center">
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap">*Manafacturer:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="manafacturer" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Model:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="model" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Year:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="year" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Type:</td>
      <td><select name="type">
        <option value="Sports" <?php if (!(strcmp("Sports", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Sports</option>
        <option value="Saloon" <?php if (!(strcmp("Saloon", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Saloon</option>
        <option value="convertable" <?php if (!(strcmp("convertable", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>convertable</option>
        <option value="truck" <?php if (!(strcmp("truck", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>truck</option>
        <option value="sedan" <?php if (!(strcmp("sedan", ""))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>sedan</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Cylinder:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cylinder" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">Cylinder cap:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cylinder_cap" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Transmissions:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="trans_count" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Trans. type:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="trans_type" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Drive_type:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="drive_type" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Fuel:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="fuel" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">Horse Power:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="hpower" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Valves:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="valves" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Interior color:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="int_color" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="left">*Exterior color:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="ext_color" value="" size="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="baseline">
      <td nowrap="nowrap" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Insert record" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

<?php printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($getCarInfo)); ?>


  <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form2" />
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error is quite clear "expects parameter 1 to be mysql**i**" and you're using the old deprecated `mysql_`

Comment: Please supply us with the full code... You don't list the query you are performing, and no info on what happens between setting up the connection and invoking mysqli_insert_id()...

Comment: as i said, i am new to PHP.. a little code would help me understand what you mean.. it does not make sense to me

Comment: @bakriawad `mysql_` and `mysqli_` are different libraries in PHP. Just as you cannot drive with your Audi to a BMW dealership and expect them to know what to do, you cannot mix them

Comment: i thought that, but the question here is there some sort of a library or cast that allows them both to interact?

Comment: No and there is no need for that. You can use the old [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-insert-id.php) if you don't want to modify the rest of the code

Comment: Is this DreamWeaver code? Uh oh. If you're new to PHP, don't start there, the code it generates is low quality and ten years out of date. Instead, find a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your style and needs and follow along with the examples given in the documentation. You'll find it's a lot easier to get things done when you've got a solid foundation to build on rather than a blank slate.

Comment: it is hard for me to read, i can process and understand codes, normal texts are hard for me... and so far, thanks to Dreamweaver and stack-overflow, i got a good grasp of PHP for a starter.. i am rewriting the whole document in my own way now.. it is hard to search for what you don't know since you do not know what to search for.. so excuse me if my questions seem vague or stupid, and thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the example supplied by [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: cant i use mysql_pconnect() or normal mysql_connect() with the mysqli_..() commands?

Comment: nope... you can use PDO though... A lot beter than using the separate functions to cleanup variables. Just search google for 'PHP PDO' and read a blogpost or two about it ;)

Comment: There are many decent [PDO introductions](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) out there, but the [main documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is a must read. No excuses for not checking that first.

Comment: @tadman Yes... But looking at the experiencelevel of OP, I would recommend first reading the first link and than the main documentation. This to make sure there is some background information why to use PDO. But you are absolutely right, main documentation is a must read!

Comment: Honestly, given their level of experience, documentation can only get you so far and a framework is an absolute **must**. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), as but one example, is significantly easier to work with than raw, low-level PHP, especially when you need to navigate a minefield of dangerously out of date references and tutorials to get anything done.

Comment: Yes... but recommending that is a bit out of scope of the question asked ;) But if you are just starting, why not write it in Ruby On Rails, or use Symfony2 or Zend? It all depends on the application which is being written (looks like a car-information-website...)